# rpcgen-passing a string inside a struct

Tags: c++, c, unix, rpc

I'm trying to pass a string as part of a structure over the network using the rpcgen packages. This is my IDL code :

```
struct param
{   
    char* name;
    int voterid;
};

program VOTECLIENT_PROG
{
        version VOTECLIENT_VERS
        {
        string ZEROIZE() = 1;
                string ADDVOTER(int) = 2;
        string VOTEFOR(param) = 3;
        string LISTCANDIDATES() = 4;
        int VOTECOUNT(string) = 5;
        } = 1;
} = 0x2345111;
```

Somehow, the string is being truncated to a single character at the server. For example, if I pass name = "abc", I get "a" at the server. It looks like this is happening because of some issue inside the stubs, but I can't seem to figure out where the bug is.

My client code for the function that passes the string as an argument :

```
void
voteclient_prog_1(char *host, char* c, int id)
{
    CLIENT *clnt;
    char * *result_3;
    param  votefor_1_arg;

#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt = clnt_create (host, VOTECLIENT_PROG, VOTECLIENT_VERS, "udp");
    if (clnt == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror (host);
        exit (1);
    }
#endif  /* DEBUG */
    votefor_1_arg.name = c;
    votefor_1_arg.voterid = id;

    result_3 = votefor_1(&votefor_1_arg, clnt);
    if (result_3 == (char **) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }
    clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt_destroy (clnt);
#endif   /* DEBUG */
}


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *host;
    int id;
    char* c = new char[20];

    if (argc < 4) {
        printf ("usage: %s server_host name voterid\n", argv[0]);
        exit (1);
    }
    host = argv[1];
    c = argv[2];
    id = atoi(argv[3]);
    voteclient_prog_1 (host, c, id);
exit (0);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be a `C++ism` that I'm not aware of, but `c=argv[2]` after you already assigned `c = new char[20]` doesn't seem right...

Comment: Actually, I wasn't sure of that myself. I was trying different things to see if I could find the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

From [rpcgen Programming Guide](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/22.rpcgen/paper.pdf), 6.9. Special Cases:

> **Strings:** C has no built-in string type, but instead uses the
> null-terminated “char *” convention. In XDR language, strings are
> declared using the “string” keyword, and compiled into “char *”s in
> the output header file. The maximum size contained in the angle
> brackets specifies the maximum number of characters allowed in the
> strings (not counting the NULL character). The maximum size may be
> left off, indicating a string of arbitrary length.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> string name<32>;   --> char *name;
> string longname<>; --> char *longname;
> ```

So, you should declare `name` like above, e. g. `string name<20>;`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding something to the comment above, the usage of this kind of array in rpcgen is like follows:

In your struct declare arrays (of any type) like this

`struct myStruct {
    //In my case I used an array of floats
    float nums<>;
}`

This declare an "array" of type float. This kind of struct has two members of variables

```
struct {
    u_int nums_len; 
    float *nums_val;
}nums;
```

Now you can allocate memory to the array of type float:

```
//totNums is the number of elements in the array
nums.nums_val = (float*)malloc(totNums*sizeof(float));
nums.nums_len = totNums;
```

Now in the server you can use your array with all the elements.